# No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' Spring Boot 2.0.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot Web application using hibernate that was running just fine on 1.5.7.RELEASE.  I decided to upgrade to 2.0.2.

All I had to do to get it compile was change the location of SpringBootServletInitializer.  However,  when I deploy to my tomcat I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

There is NO difference in my properties files or other code.  I simply change my spring version in my POM,  and I get the error.  Here is my connections configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ConnectionsConfiguration implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConnectionsConfiguration.class);

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory emFactory;

@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean fact = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    fact.setAnnotatedPackages("com.****.persistence.model");
    fact.setPackagesToScan("com.****.persistence.model");
    fact.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return fact;
}

}
```

What is the difference between 1.5.7 and 2.0.2 that is creating this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the difference is behind the scenes, but the Autowired of the EntityManagerFactory still works,  but getting the EntityManager from that factory is no longer default.  Adding the bean definition fixes the problem like this:

```
@Bean
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return emFactory.createEntityManager();
}
```

Relatively simple.